# Looking for a excellent text on ODE's

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Right now I'm searching for a text on ordinary differential equations that can be useful for reviewing over differential equations. Right now I'm after Edwards and Penney Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems and Strang's Differential Equations and Linear Algebra. For some reason I'm leaning toward Strang's text on ODE's since he has a unique style.

I'm also hearing alot of bad stuff about how strang's books are confusing.
What would be the best text for this situation.

If my math background is of importance here it is:
1. Real Analysis
2. Topology.
3. Group Theory
4. Linear Algebra

Comment: I really like "Ordinary Differential Equations" by Pontryagin, specially the stability chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some books that are good for Differential Equations, according to me:

1. Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations
   Shepley L. Ross, 4 th Edition, Wiley.
2. Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes
   George F. Simmons, John S. Robertson McGraw Hill, 2 nd edition, 1991.
3. Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems.
   William E. Boyce & Richard C. DiPrima, 10 th edition, 2012, John Wiley &
   Sons.